# About problems during package installation using cockpit program

Tags: centos, cockpit

[image]To install a package using the cockpit program
I accessed the GUI program from a web browser and later entered the software update section
The error statement is confirmed as below.

```
Loading available updates failed
Cannot update read-only repo
```

What I've tried before

- Ping Test -> Normal
- Check the yum.repos.d directory for storage privileges -> All directories have read write privileges

Is there anything else to check?